# How to pass input data to another input element in different html pages

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to pass the input value from index.html to be displayed on another input element in financial.html when clicking the ref link (calculate) so that the user doesn't need to input the same value twice on the financial.html page.

```js
function handleSubmit() {
  const income = document.getElementById('income').value;
  localStorage.setItem("INCOME", income);
  return;
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const income = localStorage.getItem("INCOME");
  document.getElementById('netIncome').innerHTML = income;
})
```

```html
<!--input element on index.html-->
<input type="number" name="income">
<a href="financial.html" onlick="handleSubmit()">Calculate</a>

<!--input element on financial.html-->
<input id="netIncome" type="number">
```

I managed to pass the value but it's not showing up in the second input box and I have to input the value again.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of `innerHTML` you want to use `value`

Comment: You could try to put the variable in a session and when you load the other page put the value of it inside the input https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp

Comment: You don't need to use localstorage to pass data between pages. You can use params for it

Comment: looks like i need to use value. will also check the link and more about params thank you!